# Lua Max Number Finder

Tags: function, lua, numbers, negative-number

Here is my code for a simple program that finds the largest number in a table, and returns the number and it's index. My problem is that the program isn't working with negatives.

```
 numbers = {1, 2, 3}

 function largest(t)
   local maxcount = 0
   local maxindex
   for index, value in pairs(t) do
    if value > maxcount then
       maxcount = value
       maxindex = index
     end
   end
   return maxcount, maxindex
 end

 print(largest(numbers))
```

This piece of code prints out "3    3". The largest number is 3, and it is in the 3rd position. When i set numbers to something like {-1, -2, -3} it returns "0    nil" instead of "-1    1".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your default values are wrong.
They should be

```
local maxcount = t[1]
local maxindex = 1
```

You were receiving "0 nil" because

- `maxindex` is undefined until the if condition `value > maxcount` is true.
- the default `maxcount` value was 0 and that's bigger than all the negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you! To get the proper index for negatives I had to set maxindex to 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 4):

`maxcount` must be set to a large negative number at start, not zero. try `-math.huge`